# Ambiguous dependency with only one @ApplicationScoped class

Tags: java, maven, jboss, cdi, wildfly-swarm

I have one class declared this way:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MessageHandlerImpl implements MessageHandler {
    ...
}
```

and I inject it on another class like this:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MessageReceiverImpl implements MessageReceiver {

    @Inject
    MessageHandler messageHandler;
    ...

}
```

When I try to start my application I receive the following exception:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001409: Ambiguous
dependencies for type MessageHandler with qualifiers @Default at
injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject
com.company.core.WSClient.messageHandler at com.company.core.WSClient.messageHandler(WSClient.java:0)
    Possible dependencies:
    - Managed Bean [class com.company.core.MessageReceiverImpl] with qualifiers [@Any @Default],
    - Managed Bean [class com.company.core.MessageReceiverImpl] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]
```

You might notice that the same class appears two times on the possible beans list.

This was all working fine until I isolated those classes on a separated project called "core" and started using them on a different maven project that has the core as a dependency.

My guess would be that the problem its caused by this project separation. Do I need to do something different when the dependencies come from a different project?

I'm running the application with:

```
mvn wildfly-swarm:run
```

Wildfly-swarm generates an uber-jar with everything to make the final jar independent. Looking inside the final jar there is a "maven repository" with all the dependencies and there is only one jar from "com.company" which is the one I was expecting (the core).

The pom files are like this:

Core:

```
<groupId>com.company</groupId>
<artifactId>core</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

Depedent project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

mvn dependency:tree

```
[INFO] com.company:dependent-project:jar:0.0.1
[INFO] +- com.company:another-project:jar:1.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.company:core:jar:0.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- info.cukes:cucumber-junit:jar:1.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- info.cukes:cucumber-core:jar:1.2.5:compile
[INFO] |     +- info.cukes:cucumber-html:jar:0.2.3:compile
[INFO] |     +- info.cukes:cucumber-jvm-deps:jar:1.0.5:compile
[INFO] |     \- info.cukes:gherkin:jar:2.12.2:compile
[INFO] +- info.cukes:cucumber-java:jar:1.2.5:test
[INFO] +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:3.4.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.zeromq:jeromq:jar:0.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.zeromq:jnacl:jar:0.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.wildfly.swarm:keycloak:jar:2017.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.wildfly.swarm:container:jar:2017.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.wildfly.swarm:spi:jar:2017.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.wildfly.swarm:config-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.wildfly.swarm:undertow:jar:2017.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.wildfly.swarm:io:jar:2017.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.wildfly.swarm:request-controller:jar:2017.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-jboss:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-jboss:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-javaee:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-base:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-javaee:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-base:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet:jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.websocket:jboss-websocket-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.undertow:undertow-servlet:jar:1.4.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- io.undertow:undertow-core:jar:1.4.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |        +- org.jboss.xnio:xnio-api:jar:3.4.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- org.jboss.xnio:xnio-nio:jar:3.4.3.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.wildfly.swarm:security:jar:2017.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.wildfly.swarm:keycloak-client-config-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.wildfly.swarm:config-api-runtime:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.keycloak:keycloak-core:jar:2.5.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.keycloak:keycloak-common:jar:2.5.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.52:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.52:compile
[INFO] +- org.wildfly.swarm:jaxrs-validator:jar:2017.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.wildfly.swarm:hibernate-validator:jar:2017.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.el:jboss-el-api_3.0_spec:jar:1.0.7.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish:javax.el-impl:jar:3.0.1-b08-jbossorg-1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.wildfly.swarm:meta-spi:jar:2017.6.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:jar:3.4.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.mapstruct:mapstruct-jdk8:jar:1.2.0.Beta2:compile
[INFO] +- org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:jar:1.2.0.Beta2:provided
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-text:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.wildfly.swarm:jpa:jar:2017.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.wildfly.swarm:datasources:jar:2017.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.ironjacamar:ironjacamar-jdbc:jar:1.3.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.wildfly.swarm:ee:jar:2017.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.wildfly.swarm:naming:jar:2017.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.enterprise.concurrent:jboss-concurrency-api_1.0_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.spec.javax.interceptor:jboss-interceptors-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.wildfly.swarm:bootstrap:jar:2017.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.modules:jboss-modules:jar:1.5.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.15:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- javax:javaee-api:jar:7.0:provided
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar:1.5.5:provided
[INFO] +- org.wildfly.swarm:ejb:jar:2017.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.wildfly.swarm:jca:jar:2017.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.wildfly.swarm:connector:jar:2017.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.jboss.spec.javax.resource:jboss-connector-api_1.7_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb:jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.ejb3:jboss-ejb3-ext-api:jar:2.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.wildfly.swarm:cdi:jar:2017.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.wildfly.swarm:cdi-config:jar:2017.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.wildfly.swarm:bean-validation:jar:2017.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.wildfly.swarm:transactions:jar:2017.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.narayana.jts:narayana-jts-idlj:jar:5.3.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.jboss.openjdk-orb:openjdk-orb:jar:8.0.6.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] +- org.wildfly.swarm:jaxrs:jar:2017.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-all:jar:5.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs:jboss-jaxrs-api_2.0_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:jar:2.7.4:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:jar:2.7.4:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.7.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.wildfly.swarm:jaxrs-cdi:jar:2017.6.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-api-maven:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-api:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-spi-maven:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-spi:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.aether:aether-api:jar:1.0.0.v20140518:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.aether:aether-impl:jar:1.0.0.v20140518:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.aether:aether-spi:jar:1.0.0.v20140518:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.aether:aether-util:jar:1.0.0.v20140518:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.aether:aether-connector-basic:jar:1.0.0.v20140518:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.aether:aether-transport-wagon:jar:1.0.0.v20140518:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-aether-provider:jar:3.2.5:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:3.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-model-builder:jar:3.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.5.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:3.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:3.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-settings-builder:jar:3.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.21:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.21:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-file:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http-lightweight:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http-shared:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.8.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.wildfly.swarm:logging:jar:2017.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided
[INFO] +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:jar:3.0.19.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation:jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1.1:provided
[INFO] +- org.jboss.resteasy:jaxrs-api:jar:3.0.6.Final:provided
[INFO] +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-validator-provider-11:jar:3.0.19.Final:provided
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-multipart-provider:jar:3.0.19.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-client:jar:3.0.19.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxb-provider:jar:3.0.19.Final:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.james:apache-mime4j:jar:0.6:provided
[INFO] +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jackson2-provider:jar:3.0.19.Final:compile
[INFO] +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.7:compile
[INFO] +- io.swagger:swagger-jaxrs:jar:1.5.16:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-core:jar:1.5.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.8.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.swagger:swagger-models:jar:1.5.16:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.16:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.reflections:reflections:jar:0.9.11:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:20.0:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:provided
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.7.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.2.4.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish:javax.el:jar:3.0.1-b08:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator-cdi:jar:5.2.4.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] +- org.postgresql:postgresql:jar:42.1.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.22:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-nop:jar:1.7.22:test
[INFO] +- org.wildfly.swarm:arquillian:jar:2017.6.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.wildfly.swarm:arquillian-daemon:jar:2017.6.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.wildfly.core:wildfly-server:jar:2.2.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.wildfly.core:wildfly-controller:jar:2.2.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.wildfly.core:wildfly-controller-client:jar:2.2.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.wildfly.core:wildfly-core-security:jar:2.2.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- org.wildfly.core:wildfly-core-security-api:jar:2.2.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.jboss:staxmapper:jar:1.2.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.wildfly.core:wildfly-domain-http-interface:jar:2.2.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.wildfly.core:wildfly-domain-management:jar:2.2.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |     \- org.picketbox:picketbox:jar:4.9.6.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.wildfly.core:wildfly-deployment-repository:jar:2.2.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.wildfly.core:wildfly-protocol:jar:2.2.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.wildfly.core:wildfly-platform-mbean:jar:2.2.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.wildfly.core:wildfly-process-controller:jar:2.2.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.wildfly.core:wildfly-remoting:jar:2.2.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.wildfly.core:wildfly-io:jar:2.2.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.wildfly.core:wildfly-network:jar:2.2.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.wildfly.core:wildfly-self-contained:jar:2.2.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.wildfly.security:wildfly-elytron:jar:1.0.2.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.wildfly.core:wildfly-version:jar:2.2.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.jboss:jboss-dmr:jar:1.3.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.jboss.invocation:jboss-invocation:jar:1.4.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.jboss.marshalling:jboss-marshalling:jar:1.4.11.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.jboss.remoting:jboss-remoting:jar:4.0.21.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.jboss.sasl:jboss-sasl:jar:1.0.5.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.jboss.stdio:jboss-stdio:jar:1.0.2.GA:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.jboss.threads:jboss-threads:jar:2.2.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.jboss:jboss-vfs:jar:3.2.12.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.wildfly.common:wildfly-common:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.msc:jboss-msc:jar:1.2.6.Final:test
[INFO] |  \- org.wildfly.swarm:arquillian-adapter:jar:2017.6.0:test
[INFO] |     +- org.wildfly.swarm:arquillian-resolver:jar:2017.6.0:test
[INFO] |     +- org.wildfly.swarm:fraction-metadata:jar:2017.6.0:test
[INFO] |     |  \- com.eclipsesource.minimal-json:minimal-json:jar:0.9.4:test
[INFO] |     +- org.wildfly.swarm:tools:jar:2017.6.0:test
[INFO] |     |  \- net.lingala.zip4j:zip4j:jar:1.3.2:test
[INFO] |     +- org.wildfly.swarm:msc:jar:2017.6.0:test
[INFO] |     +- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-spi:jar:1.1.10.Final:test
[INFO] |     +- org.jboss.arquillian.testenricher:arquillian-testenricher-cdi:jar:1.1.10.Final:test
[INFO] |     +- org.jboss.arquillian.testenricher:arquillian-testenricher-ejb:jar:1.1.10.Final:test
[INFO] |     +- org.jboss.arquillian.testenricher:arquillian-testenricher-resource:jar:1.1.10.Final:test
[INFO] |     +- org.jboss.arquillian.testenricher:arquillian-testenricher-initialcontext:jar:1.1.10.Final:test
[INFO] |     \- org.jboss.arquillian.config:arquillian-config-impl-base:jar:1.1.12.Final:test
[INFO] +- org.jboss.arquillian.junit:arquillian-junit-container:jar:1.1.10.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.junit:arquillian-junit-core:jar:1.1.10.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.test:arquillian-test-api:jar:1.1.12.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.arquillian.core:arquillian-core-api:jar:1.1.10.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.test:arquillian-test-spi:jar:1.1.10.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.arquillian.core:arquillian-core-spi:jar:1.1.10.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-test-api:jar:1.1.10.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-api:jar:1.2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-test-spi:jar:1.1.10.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.core:arquillian-core-impl-base:jar:1.1.10.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.test:arquillian-test-impl-base:jar:1.1.10.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-impl-base:jar:1.1.12.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.config:arquillian-config-api:jar:1.1.12.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-spi:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-test-impl-base:jar:1.1.10.Final:test
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-impl-base:jar:1.2.6:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-spi:jar:1.2.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:jar:0.7.9:test
[INFO] |  \- org.ow2.asm:asm-debug-all:jar:5.2:test
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:2.0.2-beta:test
[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:jar:1.6.6:test
[INFO] |  \- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-common:jar:1.6.6:test
[INFO] |     +- org.powermock:powermock-core:jar:1.6.6:test
[INFO] |     \- org.powermock:powermock-reflect:jar:1.6.6:test
[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:jar:1.6.6:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
[INFO] |  \- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito-common:jar:1.6.6:test
[INFO] |     \- org.powermock:powermock-api-support:jar:1.6.6:test
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.infinispan:infinispan-embedded:jar:9.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.12:jar:2.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.12.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.typesafe:config:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-java8-compat_2.12:jar:0.8.0:compile
[INFO] \- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.1:compile
```

Comment: What is the deployment structure? Are we talking WARs or are we in SE environment?

Comment: @Siliarus I might have misunderstood your question but this is my development environment, Java EE. The core dependency is on my local maven repository. The command I use to run my application is "mvn wildfly-swarm:run". I will add the wildfly-swarm tag on the question.

Comment: The problems  lies in at least two different jars being present in the classpath. If you tell us how the java ee is structured, together with the maven structure, you will find where the double inclusion of the jar happens

Comment: I was trying to get to what user maress suggested. Somewhere there you have included that one jar twice and CDI picked up both, or so it seems.

Comment: Can you see what jars are in WEB-INF/lib?

And also check with `mvn dependency:tree` where that dependency comes from?

Comment: @maress I edited the question with more details. The dependency on the dependent project is not duplicated. I fail to see how I'm doing the double inclusion. Do you need any more information than the one I have in my edited question?

Comment: @Siliarus do you know how I could have done that? I edited the question with more details. I don't see any duplicated jar.

Comment: @Ken I can, there is only one jar for the core in the uber-jar. I also checked the mvn dependency:tree and the core jar just appears one time. I also edited the question with more details. Could I provide any more information that you think would be useful?

Comment: @BrenoQ The only way this kind of injection arises, is when CDI happens to have loaded two beans from different jars, or somehow, wildfly-swam has loaded the same class twice using different classloaders (Unlikely though). Otherwise from the logs, i do not see anyway this can happen. If you trace carefully on your maven graph (use `mvn:dependency:tree` on the main deployable module to make sure that only one core java is available.

Comment: @maress This bean was created on the core and exists only there. I edited to add the mvn dependency:tree. Any other suggestions on what I should look for is really appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have com.company.MessageReceiverImpl and com.company.core.MessageReceiverImpl? Is this intended? I would have expected MessageHandlerImpl to be a possible dependency instead of com.company.core.MessageReceiverImpl.messageHandler

Comment: @ErhardSiegl you are correct. I tried to simplify the log with simpler names and ended up typing that mistake. My apologies. I edited the question.

Comment: @BrenoQ the uber-jar is simply a zipped file. Open it manually, look into the  lib directory, and make sure that the wildfly-swarm has not added two jars for the core module. Since you are running wildfly-swarm:run, i do not see possible module conflict or classloader problem (as would happen in a wildfly application server). The information and the error log are too few to really come up with a possible solution.

Comment: @maress That was exactly what I did. Inside the uber-jar there are all my dependencies and only one jar with my core. But I see also my own project jar inside of it. So maybe one fo the bean is coming from the core, and another bean is coming from my own project jar, that has the core inside of it, making it duplicated maybe? Does this hypothesis make sense? I will try to fix that changing the maven scope

Comment: @maress I changed the scope on my project for the core dependency from compile to provided and it didn't work. I don't get my commons library inside the uber-jar anymore so I ended up getting some NoClassDefFoundError

Comment: Now I'm thinking better about it, and maybe I shouldn't have CDI annotations on my core. Maybe I should remove all of those annotations from it and add a Producer on my dependent project

Comment: Can you try your app without using the swarm maven plugin? I am not quite sure how it creates the resulting jar but there might be something awry with the plugin. Generally speaking, your scenario is a very classic one and it should work, in fact I am pretty sure it would work if you just deploy it on plain WildFly so I think we are facing some Swarm trouble but I do not have expertise in that field.

Comment: Dependency tree looks ok.

There might be a problem in the WEB-INF/lib of your .war inside /bootstrap of the uber jar. If you can expand the WAR inside the uber jar and see what's in WEB-INF/lib, based on your error I'm expecting there to be two core jars present

Comment: You can change the logging-category org.jboss.modules to TRACE and search in the logfile for the classloader that loads MessageHandlerImpl . Maybe you find two of them.